# How to get monthly averages from Earth Engine in the Python API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I'm stumped.  It seems no one has done this in the python API.  I want to convert the Javascript below to Python.

```
 var sst = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI')
 .select('sst')
 .filterDate(ee.Date('2013-01-01'), ee.Date('2017-12-31'))

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var years = ee.List.sequence(2013, 2017);

var byMonthYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(y) {
    return months.map(function (m) {
     return sst
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
      .mean()
      .set('month', m).set('year', y);
    });
 }).flatten());
print(byMonthYear)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me (although personally i would try avoiding those nested functions cause in my opinion they make things harder to read):

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()

sst = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI').select('sst').filterDate(ee.Date('2013-01-01'), ee.Date('2017-12-31'))

months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12)
years = ee.List.sequence(2013, 2017)

def function1(y):
    def function2(m):
        return sst.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year')).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month')).mean().set('month', m).set('year', y)
    return months.map(function2)

byMonthYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(years.map(function1).flatten())

print(byMonthYear.getInfo())
```